# SKTileMapNodes vs using spritenodes with spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, nodes

So building a platformer game for iOS. You basically start in one spot, and then have to reach the exit similar to Mario or other platformers.

Currently I'm using textures that are 96x48 and 32x32 points. The 96x48 are the tops of platforms (grass) and the 32x32 points are the ground/dirt below the grass. Also, I build the levels visually within the editor.

I'm using a lot of tilemapnodes. Each platform could be 2+ tiles for the grass. I am able to rotate each platform as I see fit to get the look for the level I want. and I use the size of the tilemaps to within code create a node that I give a physicsbody too.

The problem with tilemapnodes is that each node uses a draw call. My draw count usually is around 20-25 depending on how many tilemapnodes are visible on screen.

If I were to not use these tilemapnodes, and instead just use multiple sprite nodes I could lower my draw count drastically. The drawback would be I would have a lot more nodes in the scene.

**My question:**   Are tilemapnodes going to be more efficient than the latter chose even with a higher draw count?

I know it is probably depends on a lot of other factors, but I'm trying to get a general consensus on if I should be using tilemapnodes even with a higher draw count.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Use both,  I would not be using tiles for your platforms

Comment: Having a lot more sprite nodes won't hurt performance? I guess in comparison to the lowered draw count

Comment: how many platforms do you expect on visible scene?

Comment: On visible screen, I'm not exactly sure how many platforms, it will range but anywhere from 20 - 70 sprite nodes, after I convert the tile maps to nodes

Comment: the dirt and ground are tile maps too, so I would switch that to nodes as well. so possibly more...

Comment: Almost nobody (on all of planet earth) is using SKTileMapNodes. There's rational and reasonable causes to its lack of popularity. @Knight0fDragon probably knows more about them than most, and I don't think he uses them, either. Apple rolled them out as though a fancy new checkpoint feature, and forgot a bunch of really useful and common things that go in Tile Maps, have never updated it, and then abandoned it. So if you want to go down a path less trodden, without any documentation or support, use Apple's tile maps.

Comment: I switched over to ARKit + SceneKit development.  After(in reality IF) I finish this,  I think I am going to use SKTileMap because I have an idea on a zelda / roguelike type game I may want to make

Comment: There's also a guy on these forums, Mark Brownsworld, somewhere around, who is a diverse and astute thinker and tinkerer, he knows a lot about Tile maps in general, and has experimented with Sprite Kit's variation on tile maps. Also consider this: https://github.com/mfessenden/SKTiled

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I've looked at that GitHub, preferred the built in tilemaps though. I swapped all my tilemaps and used spritenodes instead. It does seem to have lowered my memory and cpu usage slightly. Not a whole lot. I will say the level I'm building is half way built and I'm at 300ish nodes... Majority of them are static, but my draw count is less.